# How do I make visible different id's which are in "xp" namespace

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog, jquery-selectors, xpages

Basically I have a XPage where I use JQuery. On this page I have a dialog which is hidden by default(using JQuery). In this dialog I input some data which has to be validated(not empty, etc). The problem I've encountered that this has to be declared in `xp` namespace. Otherwise, JQuery doesn't recognize id declared in `xp` namespace

```
<xp:div id="dialogAddPart">
<!-- Backend code to save, validate, etc -->
</xp:div>
```

Saving, validating works, but div doesn't hide by default.

```
<div id="dialogAddPart">
//Also validating, saving (doesn't work at all)
</div>
```

JQuery statement:

```
var dialogAddPartDiv = $('#dialogAddPart');

$('#addButton').click(function() 
  {
        dialogAddPartDiv.dialog('open');
  });

  dialogAddPartDiv.dialog(
  {
  create: function (event, ui) {


                $(".ui-corner-all").css('border-bottom-right-radius','8px');
                $(".ui-corner-all").css('border-bottom-left-radius','8px');
                $(".ui-corner-all").css('border-top-right-radius','8px');
                $(".ui-corner-all").css('border-top-left-radius','8px');

                $(".ui-dialog").css('border-bottom-left-radius','0px');
                $(".ui-dialog").css('border-bottom-right-radius','0px');
                $(".ui-dialog").css('border-top-left-radius','0px');
                $(".ui-dialog").css('border-top-right-radius','0px');

                $('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').css('margin', '-25px -20px 0px 0px').css('border', 'solid 2px').css('border-radius', '15px').css('border-color', '#05788d');
                $('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').css('width', '25px').css('height', '25px');
            },

    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    beforeClose : function(event) 
    {
        if(!confirm("Close?"))
        {
        return false;
        }
        else 
        {

        }
    },
    width:600,
    resizable: false
  });
```

In the second case validating and saving don't work, but it's hide by default. How can I make `dialogAddPart` visible for JQuery in namespace `xp`?

Comment: Are you using jQuery UI? It uses AMD loading which conflicts with XPages and its Dojo. You should remove the AMD loading in order for it to work. Search SO for an answer to this.

Answer (score 1):

Add style `display: none` to your xp-div element:

```
<xp:div
    id="dialogAddPart"
    style="display: none;">
    dialogBox
</xp:div>
<xp:button
    type="button"
    id="addButton">
    +Add button
    <xp:eventHandler
        event="onclick"
        submit="false">
        <xp:this.script>
            <![CDATA[
                $("[id$='dialogAddPart']").css({ display: "inherit" });
            ]]>
        </xp:this.script>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

This will hide the div element at page load and you can make it visible by jQuery with addButton.

Comment: Well, here I have "+Add button", but when I click it, nothing happens, because it cannot find "dialogAddPart" with corresponding id :(

Comment: Get the id with `#{id:dialogAddPart}` within your CSJS code.

Comment: Do you mean add 'var dialogAddPartDiv = $('#{id:dialogAddPart}');' ? Sorry, I don't understand :(

Comment: Yes. exactly this way.

Comment: The button code has to be in XPage not in a separate file.

Comment: Added into <script> tag, no result. Anyway, thank you, this problem seems to be impossible, it's just IBM restriction.

Comment: You need a snippet for accessing JSF IDs with JQuery: https://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=x-jquery-selector-for-xpages

Comment: No, there is no restriction. It works. <script> tag doesn't help. The code has to be inside the XPage. The CSJS code gets modified on server side this way. `#{id:dialogAddPart}` gets replaced by the actual client id and the resulting code will be sent to client.

Comment: And yes, use the XSnippet Sven linked to as it handles the ":"s within id the proper way.

Comment: Knut, do I have to declare my +Add button like this?
`<xp:button type="button" id="addButton">
    +Add button
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
     refreshMode="complete">
     <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:var dialogAddPartDiv = $('#{id:dialogAddPart}');}]]></xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler></xp:button>`

Comment: @RobertBaratheon just use x$ instead of jQuerys own $ (from the code snippet linked above)

Comment: I added a working button code to show how to access div-tag per jQuery.

Comment: It works, but partly - the dialog just pops up on a page, instead being a dialog

Comment: @PerHenrikLausten
Well, it gives me an error that `x$` is not recognized. Sadly :(